# producing different lists of consecutive elements

Tags: python-3.x

I am just trying to produce the following without using numpy or any other packages.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
[41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
[61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70]
[71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80]
[81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]
[91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```

What I am trying to is to get the last element of the previous list to be the beginning of the new list in the loop but I do not know when it ends.Is it my logic that is bad? I would accept any ways to do it. here is what I done.

```
 arr= [i for i in range(1,11)]
 for i in len(arr):
      new_arr=[]
      start=[-1]
      end=# I do not know.
```

I also under the impression that I would need two loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also do:

```
result = [[*range(0,101)[i:i+10]] for i in range(1,101,10)]
print (result)
```

result:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40], [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50], [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60], [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70], [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80], [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90], [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]]
```

or:

```
for i in range(1,101,10):
    print ([*range(i,i+10)])
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
[41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
[51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]
[61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70]
[71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80]
[81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]
[91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```

note:

for example:

```
*range(1,11)
```

is producing:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

with basic double for loop you can just do:

```
 for i in range(1,101,10):
    l = []
    for j in range(i,i+10):
        l.append(j)
    print (l)
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
[41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
[51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]
[61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70]
[71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80]
[81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]
[91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```

Answer (score 2):

why not just this:

```
arr = [[10 * row + i for i in range(1, 11)] for row in range(10)]
```

a nested list-comprehension that generates your rows.

this could also be written as:

```
arr = [list(range(s, s + 10)) for s in range(1, 101, 10)]
```

Comment: Brilliant. absolutely brilliant but I had to give the point the point the t-second solution.

Comment: @Camue no worries! and happy pythoning!